# There is no VLC Media Player in my Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-installation, vlc

I can't find the VLC Media Player in the new Ubuntu Software. If i use the "apt://vlc" link from the official website, I get the message "Could not find package 'vlc'." Is VLC still available on Ubuntu or not

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: And please show us the output of `sudo apt-get update` or `grep "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @ByteCommander http://pastebin.com/4Ja4uMGN & http://pastebin.com/NMxsPQTg

Comment: Proble is solved by going to software and updates (in system settings) and selecting all options under Ubuntu tab, then running command "sudo apt-get install vlc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vlc` package is located in the `universe` repository which might be disabled in your system.

To enable it, run the command below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then update your package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you should be able to install `vlc`:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Yes it was disabled from System Settings. After enabling VLC gets installed but I still cant see it in the Ubuntu Software along with many other applications which were available in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that VLC is available as a snap package in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

```
snap find vlc
Name  Version  Developer  Notes  Summary
vlc   daily    videolan   -      The ultimate media player
```

Open a terminal and execute the following command to install VLC :

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

All necessary dependencies come installed within the snap package.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

OR

From the [official site](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html), these are the instructions to install from command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

Comment: i dont know how to use the command line but entering the first command gives this: http://pastebin.com/PaAfJwKc

Comment: edited my answer please check it.

Comment: it says "E: Unable to locate package vlc
E: Unable to locate package browser-plugin-vlc"

Comment: try a `sudo apt-get install -f` to and the rerun the commands in the answer to get apt to try and fix dependency issues.

Comment: @Karsus If the package could not be located, there are no dependency issues and `apt-get -f install` will be useless.

Comment: @XBorge What version of ubuntu do you use? you can direct download and install vlc if you want at http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/i386/vlc-dbg/download

Comment: thank you @hemnathmouli, I had to select the software sources from System Settings after which "sudo apt-get install vlc" installed VLC. But I still cant see VLC and some other softwares which I have seen in older versions. (I could download GIMP and Chromium browser from Software centre in 14.04, if I remember correctly without any command line input. Now im running 16.04.1)

Comment: @XBorge cool, enjoy ;)